# Prove if AB is one-to-one as a linear transformation, then so is B.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix, $B$ is a $k\times n$ matrix. If $AB$ is one-to-one as a linear transformation, then so is $B$.

I have been trying to prove that since $ABx = 0$ then be $Bx = 0$ and therefore must be one-to-one. I'm having a lot of trouble trying to show this. I'm also not sure if i am going in the right direction trying to prove this?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is one-to-one iff it has trivial kernel.  This implies that $\ker(AB)=\{0\}$.

Next, note that $\emptyset\subsetneq\ker(B)\subseteq\ker(AB)=\{0\}$ which implies that $\ker(B)=\{0\}$ as it is the only possible nonempty subset of $\ker(AB)$.  This further implies that $B$ is also one-to-one.

Why is $\ker(B)\subseteq\ker(AB)$?  Suppose that $x\in\ker(B)$.  Then $Bx=0$.  This implies that $(AB)x=A(Bx)=A(0)=0$ and therefore $x\in\ker(AB)$.

Comment: Would this also not be true for A?

Comment: @CodyHarris $\ker(A)\not\subseteq\ker(AB)$ (*in general.  It is possible but not guaranteed for $\ker(A)$ to be a subset*).  They might not even have vectors of the same type.  Further, $\ker(AB)=\{0\}$ does not imply that $\ker(A)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to show this would be to suppose $Bx=By$ for some $x,y$. Then try to figure out how to use the fact that $AB$ is one-to-one to show $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $B$ is one-to-one, lets assume $Bx=By$. Then $ABx=A(Bx)=A(By)=ABy\implies x=y$ since $AB$ is one-to-one. Hence $B$ is also one-to-one.